# Inno installer: How to use hi-res desktop icon?

Tags: installation, windows-installer, inno-setup

I have a couple of questions about Inno.
One is that I have a hi-res good-looking desktop icon that I made 256x256.  But when Inno installs it, a low-res one appears on the desktop.
(The one appearing in the *start menu* looks Ok and hi-res).

**Edit**: *this became a question to do with the exported format of the .ICO file (an icon file exported from Photoshop was not exporting correctly - see answers below), as well as a caching problem which was alleviated with a reboot.*

(Sometimes, when I make an icon change in Inno, its not reflected on the computer I just tested the install on.  Its only when I go to another computer and install it, do I see the new changes.  Is there a cache or something that I have to clear to see new changes?)

```
#define MyAppExeName "navdraw.exe"
#define MyAppIcoName "C:\kivymd\Inno\IGPDesktopIcon.ico"

[Setup]
SetupIconFile="C:\kivymd\Inno\IGPInstallerIcon.ico"

[Files]
Source: "C:\kivymd\exe\dist\navdraw\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
Source: "C:\kivymd\Inno\IGPDesktopIcon.ico"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion

[Icons]
Name: "{autoprograms}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; IconFilename: "C:\kivymd\Inno\IGPDesktopIcon.ico"
Name: "{autodesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; IconFilename: "C:\kivymd\Inno\IGPDesktopIcon.ico"; Tasks: desktopicon
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know why even the low res icon appears, as your script is wrong.

The [`IconFilename` parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=iconssection&anchor=IconFilename) must point to a file on the target machine. So like this:

```
IconFilename: {app}\IGPDesktopIcon.ico
```

That also explains your *"caching problem"*.

Comment: Thanks.  Hmm, maybe the icon still worked because of the `#define MyAppIcoName` ?  (I changed the line to `{app}` and its still giving me low-res for some reason)

Comment: The `#define MyAppIcoName` does not seem to have any effect in your code. + Did you test fixed script on a fresh machine? Or did you try changing the icon file name. (To overcome any caching.) + If you create very same shortcut icon manually, does it have hi-res icon?

Comment: Ah... I created a shortcut manually and used the same icon as you suggested.  It gave me low res.  So I converted it using Convertico.com rather than export direct from Photoshop, and now its looking hi-res.  (Had to reboot machine to clear cache).  Thanks.

Comment: Ok, so then please either delete your question (as you did not have a programming problem) or edit it to focus on the *"caching problem"* only.